# How to access to a variable in another structure with another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

In the first code I would like to have a selectable button, which does work for now. By following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkcVTEAl8eY. However I would like to be able to acces the information about the button being selected or not in another structure, in order to display a text. So If the button tShirt is clicked it should then display "James" in the next page", if not nothing should be displayed. An addition later on should then be that I check what buttons are selected and the display the right text. I keep running into the problem of tShirt not being within the scope, and have tried with bindings but I could not seem to get it to work. I have seen other people having close to the same issue however when trying to fix it, it never works.

*Code for selecting button.*

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectButton: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool
    @State var color: Color
    @State var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Capsule()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? color : .gray)
            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SelectButton(isSelected: .constant(false), color: .green, text: "Option")
    }
}
```

*Code for selecting button displaying the view,*

```
struct SecondView: View {
    
    
    
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView()
    }
    
    @State public var tShirt = false
    @State private var jeans = false
    @State private var polo = false
    @State private var underpants = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var alerText = ""
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .white]),
                           startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            
            
            
            Text("What are you washing today?")
            
            HStack {
                SelectButton(
                    isSelected: $tShirt,
                    color: .green,
                    text: "T-Shirt")
                .onTapGesture {
                    tShirt.toggle()

            NavigationLink(
                destination: ThirdView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Next")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            
        })
        }
        .padding()
        
        }
            }
}
```

The Last page displaying the text from the variable:

```
struct Output: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .white]),
                           startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 40.0)
                    
        
                
                Text("Best Washing Option For You!")
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
                
                VStack{
                
                HStack {
                Text("Degrees")
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 200.0)
                    
                    
                }
                    
               if tShirt == true {         //Here is the problem with scope.
                    Text("James")
                        .font(.title)     
                    
                
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 150.0)
                
                
                HStack {
                Text("Laundry detergent")
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 80.0)
                    
                }
                    
                      
                    
                }
                
            Spacer()
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}

    
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
}
```

*Note; I'm completely new to swiftUI, so im still a little confused with everything.*

Comment: If you want to share state between Views, store the state in a parent View and pass it down to the child Views via props. Don't try to reach into sibling Views. In terms of the variable being out of scope, learn about passing properties to Views -- check out the SwiftUI tutorials from Apple and Hacking with Swift

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with Bindings, not sure why it did not work for you. I'm assuming the `Output` view is the same as the `ThirdView` referenced in your question.

First, declare a `@Binding` var on your `ThirdView`. This declaration indicates that this value will be supplied by some other view or component.

```
struct ThirdView: View {
    @Binding var tShirt: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ...
        // You can use tShirt in here
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Note that I have updated the view name here
        // You can always switch between true and false here to verify your preview
        ThirdView(tShirt:.constant(true))
    }
}
```

Then in your `SecondView`:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    // This can remain private as it will be passed on as a param, instead of being accessed directly
    @State private var tShirt = false 
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ...
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ThirdView(tShirt: $tShirt), // Pass param here
            label: {
                Text("Next")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        
       })
    }
}
```